# Map tiling server in CentOS

Tags: centos, openstreetmap, mapserver

I am currently working with CentOS to create a server to host a mapping service on. I want this so I do not have to rely on other services. I have got it all working on Ubuntu but, I am a total beginner with using centos or even linux, can't seem to find a good way to create this server and get it working.

Until now I have mostly followed this [guide](https://www.keisan.io/en/knowledgebase/centos-7-open-street-map-tile-server) but did not manage to get it working properly. I have also tried to use this [guide](https://github.com/lijenpan/osm/blob/master/osm-centos7.md) but I can't get it done.

I most of the time get stuck when I need packages which yum cannot find or gives errors I cannot find a proper solution for.

Comment: Why do you want to use CentOS instead of Ubuntu? The (almost) "official" guides at http://switch2osm.org/ recommend using Ubuntu. Also, if you are stuck with a problem then you need to describe this problem and provide enough details for others to understand it. With the current state your question can't get answered.

Comment: We have a video provider for our platform which is run on a centOS server. Thats why we would like to run it on centOS. Apart from being harder to setup is there an preformance difference aswell? @scai

Comment: No, performance should be fairly equal among different distributions. Unless there are specific issues for certain software versions, which I'm not aware of. If you fail to set this up on a native CentOS then maybe you can try running a tile server in docker. Looks like this has already been done by various people. However you can expect the most support when running the Ubuntu setup from switch2osm.

Comment: @scai We were in a situation where our server admins wanted to use cent os. But now we have to use a windows based system because other software needs to run alongside it. Fortunally I got it working thourgh node js.

Comment: Good to know. Alternatively you can use Ubuntu inside a virtual machine. This will however degrade performance of your tile server.

Comment: Thanks, I am still wondering. I would like to display 3D Buildings. I know mapbox does it and I am using their mapbox gl js running on my own server. But when I try to use one of those styles I get a lot of errors. Do you have any idea?

Comment: No, sorry. Never used mapbox gl or anything similar. Better create a new question.